# Анимация пульсирует не из центра, а с правого нижнего края

Tags: css

Возможно, я сильно туплю, но почему у меня анимация происходит не по центру, а начинается с правого нижнего края и заканчивается в центре? Я же прописал правило `translate(-50%, -50%)`.

```css
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 0;
   }
}
.sk-spinner-pulse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
    border-radius: 100%;
    animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте "обёртку" для элемента:

```css
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/*NEW*/
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.sk-spinner-pulse {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ff9800;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сработало. А почему же центрирование на самом элементе не работало? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю тут проблема с translate, можно статично маргином отцентрировать в данном случае, и анимировать только scale.

```css
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
   }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
   }
}
.sk-spinner-pulse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: -30px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
    border-radius: 100%;
    animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
```

Либо указать transform-origin:

```css
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0) translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 0;
   }
}
.sk-spinner-pulse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform-origin: left top;
    animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
```

И наконец локализация поведения - проблема в порядке трансформации - сначала translate, потом scale:

```css
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
   }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
   }
}
.sk-spinner-pulse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
    border-radius: 100%;
    animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
```

Здесь фишка в том, что фактический размер элемента не меняется при scale, но менятся для трансформации.
То есть для transform размер элемента 0х0px, и он не сдвигается в центр, при этом фактический размер остается 60х60.

Comment: "О Боги", достаточно было сделать это..))

Comment: @Arthur, меня прямо заморочал этот вопрос, никак не мог найти объяснения, но даже сейчас не до конца все уложилось))) хороший урок получился